# Dark object flows over the white contour, but also flows underneath it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I've found this image on pinterest and would like to recreate this either in Adobe **Illustrator** or with **Photoshop.**
I've been searching for tutorials, but have no idea what this kind of design is called.

It's about that the dark object flows over the white contour, but also flows underneath it. Does anyone know what this is called? Can anyone help?

[image: pinterest]

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Photoshop for this. It's much easier in vector software such as Adobe Illustrator. I will assume you already know how to create the initial shapes in Illustrator.

1. With the Pen Tool, draw some shapes to cut up the black shape
2. Select all these shapes and hit *Divide* in the Pathfinder
3. Ungroup, and delete the pieces you don't need.
4. Send the larger piece to the back

Here's a rough example

[image]